# CSS glow animation keyframes work on Chrome but not iOS Safari

Tags: css, animation, webkit, mobile-safari, css-animations

Any idea why this works in Chrome but not Safari?

http://jsfiddle.net/tTxMV/

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.glow:after {
    -webkit-animation-name:             glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration:         1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
}

#btn {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="btn" class="glow">
    Start
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's **not** really that iOS doesn't support animations on pseudo-elements, it **was** more a bug from WebKit. They [solved it in January](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/) and because of Chrome's fast updates it works in Chrome now, but not so on Safari, neither mobile nor desktop version.

Make just the animation work on the entire element (`#btn`) instead of the pseudo-element.

```
.glow:after {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#btn {
    -webkit-animation-name:             glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration:         1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  ease-in-out;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tTxMV/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the point of the `:after` pseudo-element was to add a white 'mask' so the glow would work on any color. With this, the opacity of my entire element is lowered making it look more dull instead of glowing. Is there any way for me to do this as a white mask without having to add an element in front of the button?

Comment: @Garrett I just updated your fiddle, maybe you will be ok by doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tTxMV/4. No extra elements on HTML, but a bit more work on the CSS. Without adding extra markup, I think this would be the easiest way to achieve this and let your code stays a bit reusable, not at all like using pseudo-elements. Sometimes we are forced to let win the browsers :´(

Comment: I think this is as close as it gets with the Safari bug. Thanks!

Comment: @pzin: please explain me the CSS of #btn line per line. Its very difficult to understand which line i need and i can ignore if i do not need to have same text, font, color, and transparent, do i still need line-height and all those?

Comment: @YumYumYum you can change almost all the code of `#btn`, just not the animation rules, and it will still work. Those lines are just for styling but they wouldn't change the animation at all. Just play around with them and fit them to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

iOS doesn't support animations on pseudo-classes.

The bug was fixed in Webkit on January 2nd 2013 (http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632), so we might expect this to work in iOS 7 and on.

For now, can you not use the animation on the element directly (i.e. swap `.glow:after` for `.glow`, and change it to be an rgba animation rather than opacity)?